# How to using custom colormap with pixel calculation, gray scale value by opencv and make it workable on camera

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I tried to implement the mcolor colormap in the [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/337325520_Comparison_and_performance_evaluation_of_human_bio-field_visualization_algorithm)
at page 8 to 10.

I developed the code to process a [image file](https://www.chinasona.org/Thiaoouba/White-Person.jpg) and it works ok.
Now, I want to adopt this image processing method to the camera which is captured by opencv.
I implemented it by python and opencv.
It looks like that it's not workable as the computing limitation.
Can anyone give me the direction to improve it?
I expected to adopt my image processing algorithm to all frames of camera.
Thank you.
Below is my complete source code of python

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img_new = np.ones([img.shape[0], img.shape[1], 3], np.uint8)
    mcolor = np.ones([img.shape[0], img.shape[1], 3], np.uint8)
    for i in range(img.shape[0]):
        for j in range(img.shape[1]):
            val = img_gray[i][j] % 36
            if img_gray[i][j] <= 72:
                if val >= 1 and val <= 6:
                    mcolor[i][j] = (0, 0, 35)
                elif val >= 7 and val <= 12:
                    mcolor[i][j] = (i * 10, 0, 0)
                elif val >= 13 and val <= 18:
                    mcolor[i][j] = (1, 0, 35)
                elif val >= 19 and val <= 24:
                    mcolor[i][j] = (i * 20, 0, i * 20)
                elif val >= 25 and val <= 30:
                    mcolor[i][j] = (i * 10, i * 5, i * 5)
                elif val >= 31 and val <= 36:
                    mcolor[i][j] = (i * 10, 0, i * 4)
            elif img_gray[i][j] >= 73 and img_gray[i][j] <= 240:
                if val >= 1 and val <= 6:
                    mcolor[i][j] = (0, 0, i * 6)
                elif val >= 7 and val <= 12:
                    mcolor[i][j] = (0, i * 6, i * 6)
                elif val >= 13 and val <= 18:
                    mcolor[i][j] = (0, i * 6, 0)
                elif val >= 19 and val <= 24:
                    mcolor[i][j] = (i * 6, i * 6, 0)
                elif val >= 25 and val <= 30:
                    mcolor[i][j] = (i * 6, 0, i * 6)
                elif val >= 31 and val <= 36:
                    mcolor[i][j] = (i * 6, 0, 0)
            elif img_gray[i][j] > 241:
                if val >= 1 and val <= 6:
                    mcolor[i][j] = (0, i * 10, 30)
                elif val >= 7 and val <= 12:
                    mcolor[i][j] = (0, i * 10, 30)
                elif val >= 13 and val <= 18:
                    mcolor[i][j] = (0, i * 10, 30)
                elif val >= 19 and val <= 24:
                    mcolor[i][j] = (i * 10, 0, 0)
                elif val >= 25 and val <= 30:
                    mcolor[i][j] = (i * 10, 0, 0)
                elif val >= 31 and val <= 36:
                    mcolor[i][j] = (i * 10, 0, 0)

    for i in range(img.shape[0]):
        for j in range(img.shape[1]):
            b1, g1, r1 = img[i][j]
            r2, g2, b2 = mcolor[i][j]
            r, g, b = (
                min(round((int(r1) + int(r2) + 1) / 1.2), 255),
                min(round((int(g1) + int(g2) + 1) / 1.2), 255),
                min(round((int(b1) + int(b2) + 1) / 1.2), 255),
            )
            img_new[i][j] = (r, g, b)

    cv2.imshow("live", img_new)
    # cv2.imwrite("img_new.jpeg", img_new)
    # cv2.waitKey(0)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord("q"):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Can you post a sample frame that you're trying to process?

Comment: a "scientific" paper on "auras" and "third eyes"... fascinating, but absolute pseudo-scientific nonsense.

Comment: throw the entire code away, learn numpy and some basic opencv, use library functions to work on entire arrays at a time. I won't recommend numba for now.

Comment: try https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ maybe

Comment: @beaker I modified my question with the raw image file which I processed.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz ok and I will do it again. Thank you.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz ok, I already posted the complete code there. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your cascaded ifs are terrible, very inefficient (why do you recompute the modulo every time ?) and wrong (your intervals are not contiguous). Better precompute a lookup table with the output colors, having 256 (grayscale) entries.

https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/d50/group__imgproc__colormap.html

Comment: Thank you. I had enhanced my code to reduce the effort of computing. But it still costs 6 minutes to process a frame. Therefore, my code still not workable for camera. I checked the custom colormap which you provided and I have no idea to convert my code logic to a map because that I need to calcuate RGB by gray value.

Comment: 6 minutes for a single frame seems completely impossible, except maybe for gigapixel images (?). Using a color LUT should take well below a second.

Comment: I modified my original post with the image link and it's size is 7.8M.

Comment: @DavidLin: I confirm, way below a second.